# R. How to use T and F instead of TRUE and FALSE

Tags: r, logical-operators

R users can use T and F instead of TRUE and FALSE when they want to write logical values, but R output is always the long version, TRUE and FALSE.

Is there any way to force R to use T and F instead?
I mean use it in all outputs, including when you save an object to a file?

It's much neater and it takes less space on screen and in files.

I know I could replace all TRUEs for "T", and all FALSEs for "F" but this wouldn't be good because it won't be recognized as logical anymore, it would be text instead.

I think T and F aren't allowed in cran packages, but this is another story.

Comment: You should always use TRUE and FALSE

Comment: Why should I, HubertL?

Comment: Try `T <- FALSE` then try `TRUE <- FALSE` - only one of those is allowed.

Comment: Who need that definitions?.

Comment: from `?T`: TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values set to these

Comment: @HuberL, yes, I would like to change that.  Is it possible? Preferably without recompiling everything.

Comment: @skan - it's an over-the-top example, but you could also do `T <- 0` quite easily and then all of a sudden a bunch of logical comparisons are going to be switched. It's just not a "good idea"(tm) for the sake of saving a few characters of code.

Comment: In average you divide by 4.5 the number of characters.

Comment: You would have to make a special method for each use case. A good start would be writing a custom method for `print.logical`. I don't know what would go into modifying, say `write.csv` for this (terrible idea) behavior, but looking at the `write.table` code it looks like you'd need to do some modifications in C and recompile.

Comment: What about converting to numeric so FALSE becomes 0 and TRUE becomes 1?

Comment: Converting to 0 and 1 it's what I was doing before but I expected to get something working with T and F instead.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-avoid-using-t-and-f-as-synonyms-for-true-and-false/

Comment: Some people point out to avoid the usage of ```T``` and ```F``` rather than ```TRUE```and ```FALSE```. That suggestion is fine for code but may or may not be adequate for output!

Answer (score 5):

You seem confused about how `TRUE` and `FALSE` are stored:

```
> x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = TRUE)

> object.size(x)
440 bytes

> y <- sample(c(0L, 1L), 100, replace = TRUE)

> object.size(y)
440 bytes
```

Logical values are stored as `0L` ("logical zero") and `1L` ("logical one").

The storage is independent from the "look" of the object on screen:

```
> object.size(0L)
48 bytes
> object.size(0)
48 bytes
> object.size(F)
48 bytes
> object.size(FALSE)
48 bytes
```

… which means that you are not losing disk space.

Th only situation where you would be losing disk space is by saving `TRUE/FALSE` as text in a CSV file, for instance – in which case, save it as `0/1` instead.

Comment: I didn't mean the object size on memory but the size of the characters when printed on screen and when saved on a csv file.
If you have a data.frame with say 30 columns you won't be able to view it properly if you are using long names such as TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: If your "files" are all CSV, just recode to `0/1` with `as.integer`. For screen view, the answer depends on the method that you are using to "print" your objects on screen.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you. I never downvote somebody trying to help

Comment: No worries :) I'd like the down-voter to explain why, but if s/he decides not o, fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

For printing on screen you can do this:

```
x <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
class(x)
#[1] "logical"

print.logical <- function(x, ...) {
  print.default(c("F", "T")[x + 1L], quote = FALSE, ...)
}

format.logical <- function(x, ...) {
  format.default(c("F", "T")[x + 1L], ...)
}


print(x)
#[1] T F
x
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
format(x)
#[1] "T" "F"

DF <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c(FALSE, TRUE))
DF
#  a b
#1 1 F
#2 2 T
```

As you see, the implicit printing doesn't do the method dispatch for non-objects (the main reason for that is performance) and there is nothing we can do about that without changing the C code and recompiling R. You could create your own S3 class, but that wouldn't be very convenient.

For file export you can use a similar strategy of changing to a character vector, but you'll need to actually change it and can't use a `print` or `format` method. I would do that explicitly and not through S3 methods.